# platform SDK & Visual C++ in XP OS

Tags: visual-c++

I have been trying to build the sample code in platform SDK (directshow - AMCap) on visual studio 2008. i tried doing almost evrything but everytime i keep getting new errors. it is either a ' cannot find abc.h ' or a syntax error ! but the compiler is working fine. can someone tell me what i should do from scratch after installing platform SDK... Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The sample in question requires building and including DirectShow Base Classes which is under (SDK samples root)\DirectShow\BaseClasses. Build instructions can be found in SDK documentation or any DirectShow book.

If you have problems building base classes, it could be that you have a version mismatch between Windows SDK and DirectX SDK. The last version of the DirectX SDK that has DirectShow is the February 2005 version. After this version, DirectShow was moved to the Windows SDK. You may have a DirectX SDK and a Windows SDK that both have DirectShow or both miss DirectShow, depending on SDK versions.